# How Do I make Multiple Ajax Queries On A Class Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code. If I hard code the link it runs correctly. If I alert theLink I get all the different short url's alerted one by one. But when I try to pass each of these values into the ajax call the code breaks..any help would be appreciated:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

//find all the shornened urls
    $.each($('.shortenedUrl'), function(index, value) {
    inline_stats_lookup(value);             
    });

function inline_stats_lookup(theLink)
{       
    alert(theLink);
    //var theLink = "http://goo.gl/b9N1k";
    $.post('http://qrcodes.weddingdecorationss.com/tracking/inline_statistics', {url: theLink}, function(response, status, xhr) {

    if (status == 'error') 
    {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        $("#results").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
    else
    {
        //$('.clicksAllTime').empty().append('<p>' + response[0].analytics.allTime.shortUrlClicks + '</p>');
        //$('.clicksToday').empty().append('<p>' + response[0].analytics.day.shortUrlClicks + '</p>');

    }
}, "json");     


}


});
```

Comment: Are you certain you don't have trailing spaces or special character not shown in alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're looping through all anchors, and passing `value`. `value` is a `HTMLAnchorElement`.

The `.toString()` method of an anchor returns the `href` value of an anchor, that's why `alert` prints the URL.

You have to pass `value.href` instead of `value`, to get the code to work:

```
$('.shortenedUrl').each(function() { // <-- index, value not used:
    inline_stats_lookup(this.href);  // this === value for elements
});
```

Comment: Rob - thanks so much that worked a treat. It has been driving me mad since last night !